# Wonderwall app for wallpapers don't change wallpaper

Tags: 18.04, mate, desktop-background, ubuntu-mate, gsettings

I've read BingWall is a [Bing Wallpaper App for Ubuntu](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2020/02/bing-wallpaper-app-ubuntu-snap) (on OMG! Ubuntu!).

Then I installed the software `bing-wall` from a snap:

```
sudo snap install bing-wall
```

Then this app asked me to install the Wonderwall app.

So I first try to install it from a snap from https://snapcraft.io/wonderwall.

Then I see it don't work so I try to reinstall it. Then I try to uninstall `bing-wall` then reinstall `wonderwall`.

But Wonderwall doesn't work. I can't change my wallpaper with that app.

I've asked the developer of the app, and he asked me that if my distro works with `gsettings` it will work, but it doesn't.

edit : When i use `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri` it tells me :

> 'file:///home/gy0m/snap/wonderwall/20/.local/share/ktechpit/WonderWall/download/p8py7e.png'

wich is the picture file i choosed over wonderwall, but my desktop background wallpaper show the old file i choosed with the appearance/background menu.

Comment: Telling us where you obtained it from may help, I looked for a package (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=wonderwall) and didn't find it.  Was it found in *Software Boutique* or where?  (Boutique can provide 3rd party software adding sources to your system when selected)

Comment: try: `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.background active true`

Comment: do you have `gnome-tweaks` package installed? Have you tried to set wallpaper using it: **Tweaks -> Appearance**?

Comment: `gnome-tweaks` show me the file i choosed with wonderwall.

Comment: `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.background active true` is good but don't change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an answer from the developper of Wonderwall, and for ubuntu-mate gsettings works as `gsettings set org.mate.background picture-filename file url` and no `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri`.
The developper tell me he will add this implement in the next update soon.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I've done it in the next way:

- `sudo apt install bing-wall`
- Opened `bing-wall` and changed wallpaper
- `sudo snap install wonderwall`
- Opened `wonderwall` and did what it asked using the second method:

[image]

`sudo snap connect wonderwall:hardware-observe`

As a result, I could change wallpaper using `wonderwall` by first downloading and then setting it as a wallpaper.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, when i've installed first bing-wall it didn't make change wallpaper. And when  installed Wonderwall, i did the `sudo snap connect wonderwall:hardware-observe`